# Call java function from XSLT without using Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have two XSLT transformations in my code. One of them calls java function from XSLT (not supported by saxon-HE). The other does some XSLT processing which requires saxon jar.

Is there a way I can invoke the java function from XSLT with the saxon-HE jar present?

Comment: What Java function are you trying to call? When I was working on a DocBook XSLT package, it called a Java function for no particularly good reason. We programmed around the issue.

Comment: Yes, many calls to Java functions exist because the code was originally written for XSLT 1.0 or because the author was more comfortable coding in Java than in XSLT, rather than for good technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If the transform that calls a Java function is XSLT 1.0 (so doesn't have to run on Saxon) then you can use the version of `TransformerFactory.newInstance` that takes a class name, to force it to use a different transformer, e.g.

```
TransformerFactory xalanFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(
            "org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl",
            this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```